# Java: detect charset of dbf

Tags: java, encoding, dbf

I'm using `com.linuxense.javadbf.DBFReader`:

```
DBFReader reader = new DBFReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("cp866"));
```

This works as long as the file charset is cp866, but on other encodings (for example, windows-1251), cyrillic characters are broken.

The documentation says that if you call the constructor without specifying the charset, then the reader will enable autodetection, but in my case it doesn't work and I get a line like `í«¥ªâà¨ä¨ª`

How to detect the charset of dbf file in Java?

Comment: Character set autodetection is always problematic and can never be perfect. Specifying the correct encoding is the only way to guarantee you get the right data out (and yes, that implies that you need to **know** the correct encoding).

Comment: But if there are only two possible encodings you may detect it by yourself.

Comment: alexander, did you mean "two possible russian encodings"? Because there are more of them: http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file-encoding.html

Comment: Anyway, I would like a general solution.